# JSON not compiled in php

Tags: php, json, ubuntu

I installed PHP Version 5.5.1-2 on Ubuntu 12.04 and JSON was not bundled with it (as far as I can tell).

I've read that I will have to reinstall php using  the --enable-json or --with-json option.
So my questions are:

How can I verify JSON is not installed?

If not, do I reinstall php like this: apt-get install php --with-json (do I include --enable-json)?

Will my current settings be lost if I reinstall php?

Thanks

Comment: json support is there by default you should be able to use json_encode and json_decode with no problem have you tried to use them?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not there, don't know why??

Answer (score 17):

If you haven't already installed it:

`sudo apt-get install php5-json`

(more info: http://iteration99.com/2013/php-json-removed-from-php-5-5/ )

Shouldn't overwrite any other settings.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is enabled by default on ubuntu

```
#php -i | grep -i json
json
json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1
```

Comment: php -i | grep -i json returns nothing at all

Comment: Actually just try php -i and see if you get anything. You may not have php5-cli installed

Answer (score 1):

Test if `json_encode` (or any of the other JSON functions) exist.

Either call it and observe an error or use `function_exists("json_encode")`.

Comment: Response from call:Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode()

Comment: JSON is disabled then.

Comment: If I try to enable using extension=json I get the following:   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/json' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/json: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I guess you're missing the extension file. See if you can find it in the source installer or just reinstall PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't support

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

directly. the installer change it automatically to

```
sudo apt-get install php5-common
```

My recommandation should be to use  `sudo apt-get install php5-common` instead of `sudo apt-get install php5-json` because  `sudo apt-get install php5-common` will install also automatically all other dependencies for you